# How to generate a JSON value array in Azure SQL

Tags: json, azure-sql-database

```sql
DECLARE @segArr NVARCHAR(max)

set @segArr = N'[1,2,3]'

DECLARE @segTb table (
    k int,
    v NVARCHAR(20)
);
insert into @segTb
VALUES
(0, 'a'),
(1, 'b'),
(2, 'c'),
(3, 'd'),
(4, 'e'),
(5, 'f');


select t.v from @segTb t
JOIN openjson(@segArr) a on a.[key] = t.k
for JSON auto;
```

I have a simple table with a key-value like structure and a JSON array that is a list of keys of the values I wanted.

The `select` statement can create the desired result, but the JSON format is wrong. It outputs an array of objects.

```json
[
    {
        "v": "a"
    },
    {
        "v": "b"
    },
    {
        "v": "c"
    }
]
```

But what I needed is an array of direct values.

```json
[ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use more conventional string manipulation methods to create JSON arrays in Azure SQL DB such as `STRING_AGG` which aggregates strings with the given separator (eg comma) and `QUOTENAME` which surrounds strings with the given quote character.  A simple example:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME( STRING_AGG( QUOTENAME(v, '"' ), ',' ), '[' ) AS yourArray
FROM
    (
    SELECT t.v FROM @segTb t
        INNER JOIN OPENJSON(@segArr) a ON a.[key] = t.k
    ) x;
```

For your particular example you could just create a [user-defined table-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), with `CREATE TYPE`.  This would have the advantage of you being able to add a primary key to the type, to guarantee duplicates cannot be added, give the optimizer a bit more info at run-time and use native relational abilities rather than bolted-on NOSQL abilities.  A simple example which should run end-to-end:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.types st INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON st.schema_id = ss.schema_id WHERE st.name = N'tvpItems' AND ss.name = N'dbo')
    CREATE TYPE dbo.tvpItems AS TABLE
        (
            k INT PRIMARY KEY
        );
GO

DECLARE @items AS dbo.tvpItems 

INSERT INTO @items VALUES ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 )

DECLARE @segTb TABLE (
    k INT,
    v NVARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @segTb
VALUES
    (0, 'a'),
    (1, 'b'),
    (2, 'c'),
    (3, 'd'),
    (4, 'e'),
    (5, 'f');


SELECT t.v 
FROM @segTb t
    INNER JOIN @items i ON i.k = t.k
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Comment: Yeah...it looks like string manipulation is the only solution. I guess it is not a good idea to put JSON into a SQL database.

Comment: I actually regard SQL Server and Azure SQL DB as quite capable with JSON and regularly use these clauses like `FOR JSON` and `OPENJSON`, but yes it's a shame it's not a first-class citizen as a data-type with fully features methods like the one you mention, the ability to generate true JSON arrays without string manipulation.  I've extended my answer for user defined data-types which would actually work well in your use case I think.